# Timezone name (like PDT) in date field

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am having trouble with converting a date in PowerBI like:

```
Column name date:

2022-06-25 05:23:15 PDT
```

First off, after importing this file into my PowerBI project, the column above
is marked as text.  If I try to change this column type to Date/Time/Timezone in the query editor the result in an error:

```
= Table.AddColumn(#"Promoted Headers", "NewDate", each DateTimeZone.FromText([date]))

DataFormat.Error: We couldn't parse the input provided as a DateTimeZone value.
Details:
    2022-06-25 05:23:15 PDT
```

Is the use of a Timezone name a bad thing in PowerBI?  All examples I search for use a UTC offset but the date I have is so common, it seems ridiculous to have to change the data to a UTC offset.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do a conversion I'm afraid. Something like the following I think for PDT.

```
= Table.AddColumn(Source, "Custom", each DateTime.AddZone( DateTime.FromText([Column1], [Format = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"]), -7))
```

Comment: The only problem is I have many different Timezones in my file.  So, the offset will need to be different.  Extremely lame that PowerBI can't handle something so simple.

Comment: Agree that it is lame but it shouldn't be difficult to work around. How many different time zones do you have to parse?

Comment: I am not sure how many but I'm going to take a different approach and modify the script that creates the file with `PDT` and change it easily to output `-0700` instead.  This way I won't have to monkey around with a bunch of PowerBI B.S. to make it work.  Thanks for your input